# PHP DOMDocument encoding issues

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument

I have a database table holding products which is set to latin1 - default collation which can't be changed

I've written a script which uses DOMDocument to add a new li to an existing ul in the product description

The code if anyone is interested is

```
$current_description = '
    <ul>
        <li>Here is some&nbsp;broken encoding – </li>
    </ul>
';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($current_description);
$ul = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);
$li = $dom->createElement('li', 'Content');
$ul->appendChild($li);
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

I'm facing problems with encoding on the output, examples below

```
&nbsp becomes Â
– becomes â€“
```

I have searched for a solution but can't find one that works

I've tried mb_convert_encoding with varying parameters without any luck

E.g.

```
$current_description = mb_convert_encoding($current_description, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($current_description));
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you update you question and add fragment where do you set data for ** current_description** variable?

Comment: It comes directly from the database but I've added an example above

Comment: use `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>'.$current_description);
` instead

Comment: While the problem statement in the dupe is not exactly as yours, the root cause is the same: you didnt provide an encoding when loading the html snippet, so DOM will default to iso-8859-1. Adding an XML prolog with the specified encoding will change it to whatever you specified.

Comment: @gordon Thanks, but that didn't make a difference. I've run the example above but replaced the loadHTML line with yours and the end result is still the same. I also tried `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');` as in the dup but that was worse

Comment: @steveking198 not sure what you did then. Compare this [verbatim copy of your code](https://eval.in/606867) and [the same with the XML prolog added](https://eval.in/606866). The former has the â. The latter has the dash.